# Multiple Nginx Error Log Locations

Tags: linux, nginx, systemd, journald

I'm trying to get Nginx to log both in a log file and to stderr.  The reasoning behind this is that I want Nginx to log to a log file as well as to journald.  From the research and tests I've done I can make it do one or the other, but not both.

To a log file:

```
error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

To journald:

```
error_log             stderr;
```

Which I did in:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/DOMAIN.COM.conf
```

Is doing something like this possible?  If so how would it be done?

Comment: And just after I posted this I found the solution.  You just need to add each error_log entry on it's own line and now it works like a champ.

Comment: You can post that with embellishments as an [answer to your own question](http://serverfault.com/help/self-answer).